# How Move semantics Work in background

Tags: c++

Here is Example..!!
Can you explain how it works? why Destruct just one time?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    A() {
        cout << "A's Construct" << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "A's Destructr" << endl;
    }
    A(const A& obj) {
        cout << "A's Copy Constructor" << endl;
    }
};
A fun() {
    A obj;
    cout << "Fun" << endl;
    return obj;
}
int main() {
    A obj = fun();
    cout << "End" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and when I run above program output is:

```
A's Construct
Fun
End
A's Destructor
```

But When I remove Copy Constructor from the above code then Output is:

```
A's Construct
Fun
A's Destructor
End
A's Destructr
```

I'm expecting 2 Destructor for function's obj and main's obj and 1 time Copy Constructor for `A obj=fun();` and one time Simple constructor for Function's object.

**Expecting Output:**

```
A's Construct
Fun
A's Destructor
A's Copy Constructor
End
A's Destructr
```

Can you explain the difference? I know there is Move semantics or RVO But I'm confused how they performing in this code?

Compiled in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I think you should also make some debugging output for the move constructor, then it will be more clear.

Comment: @ChrisBeck how? I write the move constructor but not worked..

Comment: I don't think there is any move happening here anywhere.

Comment: @MikeMB as I expecting. There should be one Copy Constructor for Main's object and 2 Destructor? then why it showing this output?

Comment: Can't reproduce with clang : [with copy constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82fe159e67a1887e) and [without](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33ba46b680a75fb2) have the same output.

Comment: Nothing to do with move semantics, this is just [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) (and this is a duplicate of a thousand stackoverflow questions).

Comment: @JonathanWakely I tied about reading copy_elision but don't know exactly how it works. Can you explain my code please?

Comment: No, please just read about copy elision, e.g. the wikipedia article I linked to. It's been explained a thousand times already. Also read the [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) page which has an example almost exactly like yours.

Comment: Also you "Expecting Output:" makes no sense, the copy constructor cannot copy an object that has already been destroyed.

Comment: This is just [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) which has a Wikipedia page that explains it in detail. Basically, the compiler is allowed to construct the object where it needs to be after it's returned, so there's no need to make a copy because it's already where the copy would be.

Comment: @JonathanWakely VS providing my expecting output in debug mood..!! Any how I need to again read copy elision deeply and moree deeply..!!

Comment: @JonathanWakely: What I don't quite understand, is,why the OP ends up with more objects, when the user defined copy constructor is removed.(A devault move constructor should not be generated in either case right?)

Comment: @MikeMB, right, there should be no generated move ctor because of the user-defined destructor, but I gave up reasoning about VC++'s approach to copy elision long ago :)

Answer (score 1):

*...[a little time passes]...*

As one can read in the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization) of the duplicate question this result is due to compiler optimizations:

> Copy elision is an optimization implemented by most compilers to prevent extra (potentially expensive) copies in certain situations. It makes returning by value or pass-by-value feasible in practice (restrictions apply).

by @Luchian Grigore

Comment: why the destruct for just one time? Where Function's object destructor?

Comment: @simplics but I'm expecting 2 destructor and 1 copy constructor..!! Copy Constructor for main's function..

Comment: I explicitly write Copy Const, then why not printing output? can you explain please?

Comment: can you explain the output please? I'm expecting `A's Construct
Fun
A's Destructor
A's Copy Constructor
End
A's Destructr` with my copy constructor then why not this output?

Comment: I would appreciate some explanation for the negative vote. Thanks!

Comment: How is the term shallow copy relevant here?

Comment: @MikeMB  when he deletes the explicitly defined `copy constructor`  and asks: "Can you explain the difference?". One of the differences is that in the absence of copy constructor, the returning value is a shallow copy of the object inside the function (as it is not returned by reference)

Comment: HIs explicit copy constructor was a "shallow" copy too. More to the point: For a class without any datamembers, there is not difference between shallow and deep copy.

Comment: @MikeMB OK, now I got you point! I'm editing and removing the most of the speculations in my answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MikeMB now the answer is, at least contributing `0`, instead of wrong information `-1` :)

Comment: *"But on the other side you have only a default constructor, so every object instantiation is performed by it."* Doesn't make sense. There is still a (compiler generated) copy constructor and if there wasn't (e.g. when using `=delete`) The code would not compile in the first place.

Comment: @MikeMB I see, well, second edit done.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: with copy constructor, output is:

```
A's Construct
Fun
A's Copy Constructor  
//A will copy before destroying, unlike what you expecte that A should destroy before copying
A's Destructr
End
A's Destructr
```

I think is expected and self explanatory

Case 2: No copy constructor, output is,

```
A's Construct
Fun
//A has copied here by calling the default constructor provided by the compiler
A's Destructr
End
A's Destructr
```

VS2015

Comment: but with copy constructor why output is different? as you write output is expected. but VS2015 not providing that.

Comment: my VS2015 provides that output for the 2 cases from your code. The first case is expected from you and that's what i have. So no issues with that. The second case is explained below.

Comment: are you using release mode?

Comment: got the point Thanks. it's copy elision..!!

Comment: @LetDoit i edited the answer and i'm using VS2015 Enterprise.